# elasticsearch: term query fails

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a mapping for some documents and queries agains terms does fail. I don't understand why:

```
"mappings":{
     "timeslot":{
            "properties":{
                 "FOB_IN":{
                        "type":"long"
                 },
                 "TRIGGER_CODE":{
                        "type":"long"
                 },
                 "FLIGHT_PHASE":{
                        "type":"long"
                 },
                 "REP16_TRIG":{
                        "type":"long"
                 },
                 "fwot":{
                        "type":"string"
                 },
                 "FOB_OUT":{
                        "type":"long"
                 },
                 "FP":{
                        "type":"long"
                 },
                 "FLTNB":{
                        "type":"string"
                 },
                 "Date":{
                        "format":"strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
                        "type":"date"
                 }
            }
     }
}
```

I can make a term query against `TRIGGER_CODE`, for example, and it works fine

```
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 5,
      "max_score": 4.4446826,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "merged-2016-04",
            "_type": "timeslot",
            "_id": "AVRS8VnirVLwfvMnwpXb",
            "_score": 4.4446826,
            "_source": {
               "Date": "2016-04-03T08:42:44+0000",
               "FLIGHT_PHASE": 20,
               "TRIGGER_CODE": 4000,
               "fwot": "A6-APA"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

now the same **against fwot does fail**. What's wrong?

```
GET merged-2016-04/_search?size=1
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "fwot": "A6-APA"}
    }
}

{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
   }
}
```

Comment: You need `fwot` to be `"index": "not_analyzed"` for that to work. And you need to reindex the data for the above change to work.

Comment: Meaning the mapping should be like this: `"fwot":{
                        "type":"string", "index":"not_analyzed"
                 }`

Comment: query with small case.example:  "term" : { "fwot": "a6-apa"}
    }

Comment: Then you need this analyzer: `"my_custom_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": "lowercase"
        }` and this mapping `"fwot": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "my_custom_analyzer"
        }`

Comment: Or better said what exactly do you need? You seem to want to search perfect matches, but ignore the uppercase/lowercase? If so, the `term` filter is not the answer.

Comment: that's quick. I want exact match so i assume not_analysed is the the one that I want. Now, I want to change the index name, it could be the right moment: can you help me fill the new one with the current one? then destroy the old one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need fwot to be `"index": "not_analyzed"` for that to work. And you need to reindex the data for the above change to work.

Here's the complete list of commands for the mapping change and some test data:

```
PUT /merged-2016-04
{
  "mappings": {
    "timeslot": {
      "properties": {
        "FOB_IN": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "TRIGGER_CODE": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "FLIGHT_PHASE": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "REP16_TRIG": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "fwot": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "FOB_OUT": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "FP": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "FLTNB": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Date": {
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /merged-2016-04/timeslot
{
  "Date": "2016-04-03T08:42:44+0000",
  "FLIGHT_PHASE": 20,
  "TRIGGER_CODE": 4000,
  "fwot": "A6-APA"
}

GET merged-2016-04/_search?size=1
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "fwot": "A6-APA"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the doc page [Query DLS term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/query-dsl-term-query.html), note "*Why doesn’t the `term` query match my document*" for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

We Can use keyword

```
GET merged-2016-04/_search?size=1
{
  "query": {
      "term": {
        "fwot.keyword": "A6-APA"  
      }
   }
}
```