# Elasticsearch query on nested data structure

Tags: elasticsearch, wikidata

I have indexed into elasticsearch a wikidata dump. I have a nested structure of my objects, with some subfields that are duplicate in the same field. I show you the structure of only one object:

```
 "hits": {
  "total": 10397696,
  "max_score": 1,
  "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "wikidata",
        "_type": "items",
        "_id": "Q1534812",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "id": "Q1534812",
           "labels": [
              {
                 "lang": "gsw",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "Wikimedia-Begriffsklärigssite"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "sk",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "rozlišovacia stránka"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "ro",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "pagină de dezambiguizare Wikimedia"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "is",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "aðgreiningarsíða á Wikipediu"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "sw",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "ia",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "zu",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "oc",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "en-gb",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "Wikimedia disambiguation page"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "he",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "דף פירושונים"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "zh-hans",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "维基百科消歧义页"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "gu",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "સ્પષ્ટતા પાનું"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "cs",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "rozcestník"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "bn",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "উইকিমিডিয়া দ্ব্যর্থতা নিরসন পাতা"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "pt",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "página de desambiguação de um projeto da Wikimedia"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "et",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "Wikimedia täpsustuslehekülg"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "frp",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "gl",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "páxina de homónimos"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "ca",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "pàgina de desambiguació de Wikimedia"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "kg",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "ast",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "fa",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "یک صفحهٔ ابهام‌زدایی ویکی‌مدیا"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "or",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "ବହୁବିକଳ୍ପ ପୃଷ୍ଠା"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "en",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "Wikipedia disambiguation page"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "tr",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "Vikimedya anlam ayrımı sayfası"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "mk",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "појаснителна страница"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "pt-br",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "página de desambiguação de um projeto da Wikimedia"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "wo",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "ka",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "მრავალმნიშვნელოვანი"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "af",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "cy",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "sv",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "grensida"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "pcd",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "li",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "ar",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "صفحة توضيح لويكيميديا"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "lij",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "ckb",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "پەڕەی ڕوونکردنەوەی ویکیمیدیا"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "fr",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "page d'homonymie d'un projet Wikimédia"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "fi",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "täsmennyssivu"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "io",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "zh",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "维基百科消歧义页"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "fur",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "ms",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "Laman nyahkekaburan"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "co",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "nrm",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "de",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "Wikimedia-Begriffsklärungsseite"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "nds",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "Sied för en mehrdüdig Begreep op Wikipedia"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "de-at",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "es",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "página de desambiguación de Wikimedia"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "mg",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "nds-nl",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "bg",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "Пояснителна страница"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "lb",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "Wikimedia-Homonymiesäit"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "ko",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "위키백과 동음이의어 문서"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "vo",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "ja",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "ウィキペディアの曖昧さ回避ページ"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "nl",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "doorverwijspagina"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "pms",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "nap",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "min",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "laman disambiguasi"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "bs",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "čvor stranica na Wikimediji"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "sco",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "Wikimedia disambiguation page"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "hu",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "egyértelműsítő lap"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "an",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "vi",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "trang định hướng Wikimedia"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "sc",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "sl",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "ga",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "it",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "pagina di disambiguazione di un progetto Wikimedia"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "en-ca",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "Wikimedia disambiguation page"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "gd",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "el",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "σελίδα αποσαφήνισης"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "pl",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "strona ujednoznaczniająca"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "ie",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "hr",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "razdvojbena stranica na Wikimediji"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "eu",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "hi",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "बहुविकल्पी पृष्ठ"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "rm",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "sr",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "вишезначна одредница на Викимедији"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "nb",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "Wikimedia-pekerside"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "zh-hant",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "維基百科消歧義頁"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "lv",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "Wikimedia projekta nozīmju atdalīšanas lapa"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "br",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "vec",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "de-ch",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "nn",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "Wikimedia-fleirtydingsside"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "vls",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "da",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "Wikimedia-flertydigside"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "eo",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "apartigilo"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "scn",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "wa",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "ru",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "страница значений"
              },
              {
                 "lang": "sr-el",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "bar",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": []
              },
              {
                 "lang": "id",
                 "name": "Goldelse",
                 "aliases": [],
                 "description": "Halaman disambiguasi"
              }
           ],
           "claims": [
              {
                 "id": "Q1534812$EC5863FD-D913-4CE4-9198-E3E7A82FA6B0",
                 "propertyId": "P31",
                 "rank": "Normal",
                 "type": "statement",
                 "qualifiersOrder": [],
                 "mainSnak": {
                    "snakType": "HasValue",
                    "propertyId": "P31",
                    "dataType": "WikibaseItem",
                    "dataValue": {
                       "wikiItemId": 4167410
                    }
                 }
              }
           ],
           "siteLinks": [
              {
                 "site": "dewiki",
                 "title": "Goldelse",
                 "badges": []
              }
           ]
        }
     },
```

I can't find a way to make any kind of research for labels.name or claims.mainSnak.dataValue.wikiItemId- two of subfields that are presents more times in a field. How I can do that?

Comment: Look at the mapping of the index and see what kind of field `claims` and `labels` is.

Comment: Both of fields are nested type

Comment: You need to use nested query https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html

Comment: I have just tried {"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"match_all":{}},"filter":{"nested":{"path":"labels","filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"labels.name":"Francesco Totti"},"term":{"labels.lang":"it"}}]}}}}}}} and something similar, but without results

Comment: For this - `{"term":{"labels.name":"Francesco Totti"}` - to work you need `labels.name` to be `"index": "not_analyzed"`. You basically are doing the same mistake as in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36889057/elasticsearch-term-query-fails/36889895#36889895). It's a very common mistake though. You just need a little bit of reading about Elasticsearch.

Comment: Putting WikiData in ElasticSearch is a fantastic idea! Do you want to share the process of doing it?

Comment: @leo you might be interested in the work I have done in this repo https://github.com/inventaire/wikidata-subset-search-engine , which is basically a dump of Wikidata filtered using wikidata-filter https://github.com/maxlath/wikidata-filter and put to elasticsearch